# How to return the first array element in the function?

Tags: arrays, return

Examples
getFirstValue([1, 2, 3]) ➞ 1

getFirstValue([80, 5, 100]) ➞ 80

Answer (score 0):

for example

```
function getFirstValue($array){
    return $array[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What language are you working in? The syntax will change slightly depending on the specific language, but most of the popular languages allow you to access elements in a list/array like this: `aList[0]` where 0 indicates the first element of the list. If you are working in python, for example, the function definition would look like this

```
def getFirstValue(aList):
    return aList[0]
```